# Order Confirmation email must populate Country Currency locale via ampscript but does not work (formatcurrency)

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, locale

When an order occurs on the website, Marketing cloud holds the country locale of `en_US` and `en_CA` in a Data Extension field titled "locale"

The following ampscript is not pulling in the country locale stored in the DE to update. `en_US` pricing displays regardless of what is in the "locale" field so formatcurrency is not working:

```
%%[ VAR @Subtotal 
VAR @ShippingPrice 
VAR @TaxPrice 
VAR @Totalprice 
VAR @DiscountsSavings 
VAR @locale set @locale = AttributeValue("locale") 
SET @SubtotalPrice = [SubtotalPrice] 
SET @ShippingPrice = [ShippingPrice] 
SET @TaxPrice = [TaxPrice] 
SET @TotalPrice = [TotalPrice] 
SET @DiscountsSavings = [DiscountsSavings] 
IF @locale == "en-CA" 
then 
SET @SubtotalPrice = FormatCurrency(@locale, "en_CA") 
SET @ShippingPrice = FormatCurrency(@locale, "en_CA") 
SET @TaxPrice = FormatCurrency(@locale, "en_CA") 
SET @TotalPrice = FormatCurrency(@locale, "en_CA") 
SET @DiscountsSavings = FormatCurrency(@locale, "en_CA") 

ENDIF 

else set @locale = "en_US" ]%%
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. Looks like there's a typo in the if condition, shouldn't it be `en_CA` (with an underscore) ?

Comment: @shamina, updated en_CA but now getting this error message:

An error occurred when attempting to evaluate a FormatCurrency function call. The input value (en_CA) cannot be formatted as a number. The first parameter value for a FormatNumber call must be a numeric type supported by the requested format. Value: en_CA Format: C

Comment: ISO Culture codes use hyphens, not underscores. Try "en-CA".